# sudo without password is not giving any output

Tags: shell, sudo

all "myscript.sh" does right now is echo "hello".

```
[jack@server1 scripts]$ ./myscript.sh
hello
```

the root user gave me the option to run the script as root without a password but when I do, the script doesn't print the "hello"

```
[jack@server1 scripts]$ sudo ./myscript.sh
Password:
[jack@server1 scripts]$
```

what am I doing wrong here? do I need to add some kind of switch ?
I don't see anything about this in man sudo

by the way, obviously I don't have root access to configure anything about this

this is the content of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash +xv
echo "hello"
```

and about the permissions and ownership:

```
[jack@server1 scripts]$ls -l myscript.sh
-rwxrwxr-x  1 jack SiteAdmin 1279 Dec  4 07:54 myscript.sh
```

Comment: The default shell for root and your user can be different. Add at beginning `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Also it may have no execute permissions for everyone, try `chmod a+x myscript.sh`

Comment: right now it's: `#!/bin/bash +xv` .
is that ok?

Comment: I did the chmod, same result

Comment: Please first try putting the script through [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) to check for obvious errors. After fixing anything critical from there, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47637326/edit) and show us the script as it is now, as well as the output of `ls -l myscript.sh`. It is very difficult to replicate results and diagnose a problem when we don't have all the information.

Comment: There's also the question of whether the person who had root actually set up the `/etc/sudoers` entry for your script *correctly*. Without their cooperation, this isn't necessarily possible to debug.

Comment: "obviously I don't have root access" uhm you appear to have complete, untethered root access via `sudo`

Comment: i edited the question, added the contents of the file and the `ls -l myscript.sh` command.
@thatotherguy , it's the system administrator that said he gave me root for running the scripts. but both me or him might be mistaken.

Comment: have you try this way, sudo sh myscript.sh ??